# Special case of Karatsuba algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, recurrence

I need some help with the following problem:

Let's consider a computer with word length of sqrt(n) bits. That means that any  multiplication between 2 sqrt(n)-bit integers is O(1).
The problem is to prove that the complexity of doing with this computer the multiplication of 2 n-bit integers using the Karatsuba algorithm is O(n^1.29).

I have tried to write a recursive relation like:
        T(sqrt(n)) = 3T(sqrt(n)/2) + Θ(sqrt(n))

Then, by replacing sqrt(n) with n, I end up with: T(n) = 3T(n/2) + Θ(n)
which gives T(n) = Θ(n^1.58).

I can't understand where I have made a mistake.
Thank you very much!!

Comment: After trying to do your homework ask the tutor for an answer

Comment: I suggest adding other relevant tags like `recurrence` and `time-complexity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly stated that the original recurrence relation is `T(n) = 3T(n/2) + Θ(n)`; the logical error you made was to directly replace `n` with `sqrt(n)`.

What you must instead do here is re-derive the time complexity with a different *stopping condition* - i.e. `T(m) = O(1) Ɐ m ≤ sqrt(n)`. The given result `T(n) = Θ(n^1.58)` follows from making the stopping condition equal to some small constant, which is not the case here.

Let's repeatedly expand this recurrence:

[image]

... and apply the modified stopping condition:

[image]

... using some logarithm laws. And thus we arrive at:

> [image]

... which is the required result.